# Validate environment variables in Docker

Tags: docker, assert

Is there any kind of ASSERT in Docker?

In this specific case I want to be able to validate that an environment variable has been set and force the build to fail if it hasn't.

The code that has caused me issues is:

```
echo ${LICENSE_KEY} > /etc/license.key
```

I have been tasked with getting a previous employee's code working correctly and have found that this file was empty. It strikes me that this variable being unset should be fatal for this build script and would have saved me lots of debugging.

From my reading of the Docker docs (since Docker 0.7) I can run a shell command that returns a non zero status and that would cause the build to fail. e.g.

```
RUN [ ! -z "${LICENSE_KEY}" ]
```

Though this will cause extra layers and code in the image, that may not be obvious to others that it is just there for debugging/protection and does not explicitly state the reason for the failure when combined with other commands. I was really expecting docker to have something akin to:

```
ASSERT ${LICENSE_KEY} != ""
```

Comment: 1) Your solution won't cause an extra layer, because there is no change to the filesystem.
2) A comment in the Dockerfile would surely be enough to tell others the purpose?

Comment: I did not expect that from reading this https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run specifically  - "The RUN instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results. The resulting committed image will be used for the next step in the Dockerfile."

Comment: I would expect this would create an extra layer; but if you're using layers responsibly and a single layer had all the build-time checks, it wouldn't be a big deal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and I did something like:

```
RUN [ ! -z "${LICENSE_KEY}" ] || { echo "License key cannot be empty"; exit 1; } && \
    ... other run commands ...
```

Comment: It is solution best for me. I know it is extended version of @Martin response, but thi echo command is what I needed.

Comment: The or and the echo are definitely an important improvement, @Martin himself recognized that inserting the simple test in a long RUN command claims for readibility; with this technique one can have any desired message.

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution I have used, but an ASSERT that didn't create any layers would be better.

```
ARG LICENSE_KEY
RUN [ ! -z "${LICENSE_KEY}" ] # Assert LICENSE_KEY is defined
```

Pass case

```
Step 2/10 : ARG LICENSE_KEY
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e5fba6cf457c
Step 3/10 : RUN [ ! -z "${LICENSE_KEY}" ] # Assert LICENSE_KEY is defined
 ---> Running in 7e83e02e7372
 Removing intermediate container 7e83e02e7372
 ---> c31d8da7b006
```

fail case

```
Step 2/10 : ARG LICENSE_KEY
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e5fba6cf457c
Step 3/10 : RUN [ ! -z "${LICENSE_KEY}" ] # Assert LICENSE_KEY is defined
 ---> Running in 0d10210c8bca
The command '/bin/sh -c [ ! -z "${LICENSE_KEY}" ] # Assert LICENSE_KEY is defined' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

It definitely creates extra 0 byte layers though. As can be seen from running:

```
docker history --no-trunc <image>

sha256:fe9<...snip...>   About an hour ago   |1 LICENSE_KEY=some-key /bin/sh -c [ ! -z "${LICENSE_KEY}" ] # Assert LICENSE_KEY is defined    0B
sha256:e5f<...snip...>   About an hour ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ARG LICENSE_KEY                                                              0B                                                                                                                                                
sha256:5e8<...snip...>   4 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/bash"]                                                            0B
```

Comment: You can simply chain this with a later RUN command that uses the license key later in the build. If they are both a single RUN statement, then you won't be adding additional layers or disk usage.

Comment: That was how I did it originally. i.e. at the start of the long line of yum update && \ yum install ... etc ... && \ echo ${key} > file.key  -  The problem is you get a single failure for the entire command set and it is not obvious that the assert has fired and potentially quite confusing when the assert is not the reason for the failure.